# How to get the actual class of the annotation?

Tags: kotlin

This is run by a Spring Interceptor from `ProceedingJoinPoint`

```
fun myMethod(methodSignature : MethodSignature){
    val params : Array<Parameter>? = methodSignature.method.parameters

    if(params != null && params.isNotEmpty){
        params.forEachIndexed{
            index, parameter ->
            for(annotation in parameter.annotations){
                println(AopUtils.getTargetClass(annotation))
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Currently, I am only seeing Proxy classes (eg `com.sun.proxy.$Proxy123` and not `MyAnnotation`) in the `println`. How to get the actual annotation class? Yes, the annotation was written in Kotlin.